# QtreeWidget python read the state of the checked boxes

Tags: python, pyqt5

First sorry if I am missing anything.and sorry about the format, new to stackoverflow
I am trying to read the flag state from a QtreeWidget.
I have tried a lot of things and nothing seam to work.
I am dynamical creating the tree as follows

```
        Part=str(result2[row2][0])
        qty=str(offset_B)+str(result2[row2][1])
        instock=str(offset_B)+str(result2[row2][2])
    
        B = QTreeWidgetItem(A, [Part,qty,instock])
        B.setForeground(0,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color_item)))
        B.setForeground(1,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color_item))) 
        B.setForeground(2,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(color_item)))    
        B.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsTristate)
        B.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
```

I have a button Generate Po's and when I click it I want to iterate through the items and grab the text value of the checked Items.

sample [image]

so it should return a list of some sort with all the text field.
I can do the list I just need to understand how to grab the "State" of the button.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: [`item.checkState()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#checkState).

Comment: Thank you I did try it but probably didn't do it write. how do I iterate through the list to check each index for this state.

Comment: You said "I can do the list". How do you do it? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: thank you I will figure it out. the formatting on this page is honorific to post code.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "the formatting on this page is honorific to post code"?